# Is there a way to add a row in a EX Grid by click in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a EXGRIDLibCtl, and I want for the user to be able to enter data into an empty cell. Is this possible. Sorry if this is a re-post, I am still a noob. could you please direct me to the right spot. Thanks so much!

Comment: Unfortunately your question is likely to be closed as it gives us very little info to help you. Why not go to the [source](http://www.exontrol.net/content/products/exgrid/howto/how_to_do_vb6.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the link C-Pound Guru.

Comment: No problem.  It was the 2nd or 3rd link when I searched for 'EXGRIDLibCtl' in Google.  Google is your friend.